# Export data from jira into Excel

Tags: jira

When I export results of jql query to Excel and try to open this .xls file with results. It doesn't open in Excel 2016. Does anyone faced such problem? What are the solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure that the problem relies on jql export? 
I've seen some posts around about excel 2016 & .xls incompatibility. 
Try an online free excel reader (i.e Google Spreadsheet) to make sure that its the file that is corrupted.

You can read about that bug [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-excel/need-to-open-xls-files-with-excel-2016win10/e6f1568f-e23d-4bcf-aa6d-742e625f0ec8?auth=1).

goodluck